# Unable to cast object of type '<XYPairsInRange>d__8' to type 'IXYPair'

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

in `EnumerablePointEnumerator<T>.GetCurrent(ref Point p)` (`Microsoft.Research.DynamicDataDisplay.DataSources`) I'm getting an error `Unable to cast object of type '<XYPairsInRange>d__8' to type 'IXYPair'.`

XYPairsInRange is not a type, but a method of my class, of return Type IEnumerable

```
public IEnumerable<IXYPair> XYPairsInRange(double startX, double endX)
{
   foreach (IXYPair pair in this.XYPairs)
   {
      if (pair.X >= startX && pair.X <= endX)
      {
         yield return pair;
      }
   }
}

public IEnumerable<IXYPair> XYPairs
{
   get
   {
       int counter = 0;
       foreach (double x in XValues)
       {
          yield return new XYPair() { X = x, Y = YValues[counter++] };
       }
   }
}
```

IXYPair is defined as

```
public interface IXYPair
{
    double X { get; }
    double Y { get; }
}
```

What could cause this error at runtime? I've tried explicity casting the yield return statement and returning a list (without yield) with no success

EDIT: XValues and YValues are both List< double >

Calling code:

```
public IEnumerable Query()
    {
        yield return this.Data.XYPairsInRange(Double.NegativeInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity);
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of `XValues`?

Comment: Show your calling code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're yielding an enumerator from your `Query()` method, not items from the enumerator:

This:

```
public IEnumerable Query()
{
    yield return this.Data.XYPairsInRange(Double.NegativeInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity);
}
```

Could be rewritten as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IXYPair>> Query()
```

And now you should spot why this is not working.

You should rewrite the body of the method to this:

```
public IEnumerable<IXYPair> Query()
{
    return this.Data.XYPairsInRange(...);
}
```

or to this (the above is preferred):

```
public IEnumerable<IXYPair> Query()
{
    foreach (var pair in this.Data.XYPairsInRange(...))
        yield return pair;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it seems to work without any problem:

```
public interface IXYPair {
    double X { get; }
    double Y { get; }
}

class XYPair : IXYPair {
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }

    public override string ToString( ) {
        return string.Format( "X = {0} ; Y = {1}", X, Y );
    }
}

class Program {
    static List<double> XValues;
    static List<double> YValues;

    static void Main( string[ ] args ) {
        XValues = new List<double>( ) { 0.05, 0.25, 0.85, 0.95, 0.35, 1.65, 115.25 };
        YValues = new List<double>( ) { 0.25, 0.85, 1.15, 12.95, 7.35, 1.75, 0.13 };

        foreach ( IXYPair pair in XYPairsInRange( 0.5, 1.5 ) )
            Console.WriteLine( pair.ToString() );
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IXYPair> XYPairsInRange( double startX, double endX ) {
        foreach ( IXYPair pair in XYPairs ) {
            if ( pair.X >= startX && pair.X <= endX ) {
                yield return pair;
            }
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IXYPair> XYPairs {
        get {
            int counter = 0;
            foreach ( double x in XValues ) {
                yield return new XYPair( ) { X = x, Y = YValues[ counter++ ] };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

> X = 0.85 ; Y = 1.15 
>   X = 0.95 ; Y = 12.95

Comment: Thanks, I tried out the code on its own too and it works fine, my problem seems to be with the DynamicDataDisplay.DataSources EnumerablePointEnumerator<T>.GetCurrent(ref Point p). Do you know why I would get a method name coming up as a type?

Comment: The problem is in the `Query` method, see my answer.